# trouble in finding a sample for serial connection in react native

Tags: react-native, serial-port

hello everyone i need to make a react-native project to test and practice usb serial connection but im not able to find any example project or youtube toturial. Any suggestions for me?

Comment: Don't search for "USB serial", search for "serial port" (in combination with react-native). From the app's view, it just a serial port. There is no special API for serial connection over USB.